# Mysql cursor is not fetching any data

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I want to make one SELECT query from python to mysql DB.
But I'm getting an empty list when I call `cursor.fetchall()`
I have already tested the connection and the query with DBeaver, and it works fine.
I tried following the tutorials on https://dev.mysql.com but didn work.
Here is my function:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import connect

def execute_query_2(self,query):
        connection = connect(
                host="config.host",
                database="config.db_name",
                user="config.db_user",
                password="config.db_user"
            )
        print(connection)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        for row in result:
            print(row)
```

The `print(connection)` gives me `mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x7f6a725bfca0`.
Also the query is being loaded successfully as `'SELECT * from occUserManager.addressInformation'`.
The result for this should bring 44 rows.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: I think it's necessary `connection.commit()` after `cursor.execute()`

Comment: You do not have to commit for `SELECT` statements iirc

Comment: @CarMoreno I share your oppinion. But even on MySQL  homepage there is no cursor.commit() statement at their example.

Comment: @snakecharmerb but `result` is a variable... they are calling `fetchall()` only ONCE, and storing into variable `result`. This makes it such that you can use `result` how many ever times you'd like to, since it's just a list and not a generator